# Cerrar un BufferedReader

Tags: java, eclipse

Mi pregunta es si es estrictamente obligatorio cerrar un `BufferedReader` con `.close()`.

Estoy practicando con lectura y escritura de archivos y, por ejemplo, si un `BufferedWriter` no lo cierras con `.close()` no hace nada, por tanto es obligatorio cerrarlo.

Ocurre lo mismo con `BufferedReader`, es decir, es estrictamente obligatorio cerrarlo? O se puede dejar sin cerrar? Hay algun inconveniente?

Comment: "No hace nada" no es correcto. Te recomiendo leer sobre memory leaks.

Comment: Lo que se quiere, que es que en el archivo de salida salga escrito lo que queremos que salga escrito, no lo hace. Solo cuando lo cierras con .close() lo hace. Aun así, te agradecería que me dijeras donde leer la documentación que mencionaste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no es estrictamente obligatorio cerrar los BufferedReader, pero es una buena práctica hacerlos, ya que al cerrar un BufferedReader estas liberando recursos que ya no necesitas. Que ocurre si vas dejando BufferedReader sin cerrar pues posiblemente tu aplicación tenga problemas de memoria y rendimiento.

Así que el consejo que te doy es que cierres todos los BufferedReader y BufferedWriter que ya no necesites.

No se que versión de java estas utilizando, pero a partir de Java 7 puedes hacer eso de:

```
try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"))){
    String linea;
    while ((linea = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(linea);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A esto se le llama *try-with-resources* lo que se ha declarado dentro de la sentencia `try` se cerrará automáticamente cuando el bloque de sentencias que se encuentren en `try` sean ejecutadas completamente.

Comment: Utilizo la versión mas reciente puesto que tuve que instalar tanto Java como Eclipse hace poco. No sabía lo de los recursos de memoria asi que genial, me lo apunto ;) gracias!

Comment: Si te ha servido puedes marcarlo como respuesta. Me alegra que te sirviera :)